# What is the mean of $\operatorname{sinc}(t)$ (cardinal sine)?

Tags: integration, average, means

Can the mean of $\operatorname{sinc}(t)=\frac{\sin(t)}{t}$ be calculated over the entire $t$ domain, i.e., $$\int_{a}^{b}\frac{\operatorname{sinc}(t)}{b-a}dt,\text{ where } a=-\infty, \ b=\infty?$$  Can the calculation be approximated somehow using limits? I have a feeling the mean exists by just looking at a graph the function. The function itself isn't defined at $t=0$, therefore the definition $$\operatorname{sinc}(t)=\begin{cases}1,&\quad t=0,\\\frac{\sin(t)}{t},&\quad \mathrm{otherwise},\end{cases}$$ is used.

Can the calculation be split into two or three sections?

Comment: The integral of $\mathrm{sinc}$ over the whole real line is $\pi$, so the mean should be equal to $0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Dirichlet integral is

$$\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{\sin(x)}{x}dx=\frac{\pi}{2}$$

$\implies$

$$\lim_{(a,b)\to(-\infty,+\infty)}\int_a^b\frac{\sin(x)}{x}dx=\pi$$

$\implies$

$$\lim_{(a,b)\to (-\infty,+\infty)}\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b \frac{ \sin(x)}{x}dx=0.$$

Answer (score 0):

I would argue, that the mean $\bar x$ of a sinc is not properly defined, if it is defined in its custom way as

$\bar x:=\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty x \frac{\sin x}{x}\,dx$

in close similarity to the [Cauchy Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution). Using the definition of the OP and the line of argumentation by @Salahamam_Fatima, would not the mean of the positive half of a Gaussian be

$\lim\limits_{a\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{a} \int\limits_0^a e^{-x^2}\,dx=0$ ?